# Is it possible to edit a HTML page from a different file?

Tags: html, crystal-reports

I hope this doesn't sound confusing. Basically, I am trying to reload a web page because the report data is refreshed every minute. yes I know about refreshing using javascript and the meta tag in html. However, the problem is that the HTML is generated from Crystal Reports. Meaning the entire HTML file is created from the report and we are not able to edit the HTML within Crystal Reports before it's exported to the web server. So my question is, how can I edit a HTML page, that is created in Crystal Reports and exported to the web server, without being able to edit the code of the html report page? is it even possible? or if someone is savvy with Crystal Reports is there a way to edit HTML on the report?

In the future the plan is to move away from Crystal reports and create the report and html with PHP. so this is my fall back plan but for now just trying to get this refresh/reload to work.

Comment: Just to clarify. You have (a) a generated HTML, not on the webserver (b) a script of some sort on your webserver, and (c) and HTML on your webserver that you want to output the report to, right? What type of server are you using and if you have a script file, what language?

Comment: Hello Jack, Ill try to explain best I can. We do have a generated HTML file however it is exported to the webserver so it is in the same directory as the main HTML files for our intranet. Crystal Reports generates the HTML file and saves it to the directory under a specific name that is used in a link <a href="file.html> when you click that link it opens a new webpage with the report. So, no scripting on our side and our web server is IIS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the `<iframe>` tag would work best in your sitatution.

You can create a wrapper of sorts that will allow you add your auto-refresh meta tag (Or you could do it will JS if you like)

Try something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
    <style>
       html, body {
         margin: 0px;
         overflow: hidden;
       }

       iframe {
         height: 100vh;
         width: 100vw;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe  src="report.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```